# Image and Media control do not accept the drop even after Allow drop is true

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In Silverlight 4, I have a button with AllowDrop = True. If I drag a file and drop on this Button, drop event fires up and I write some code in it (regardless of whether I run Elevated or Non-Elevated!)

Same drop event doesn't seem to work for at least 2 controls, mediaelement and image control. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, got this one fixed. Basically, if you have don't assign a source to the image or media control, then there's nothing to hit test against for that control, so hittesting fails and the event is not fired on the control.

Will keep everyone posted in case I find more.